# Why does my website have different view in Android and IOS?

Tags: android, html, ios, css

This is how my website looks like in an iOS browser. 
[IOS view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmuUS.jpg)

But when my friend opens my website in an Android browser it looks horrible: [Like this Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP7LM.jpg)

Please suggest some advice what to do with this kind of problem.

Here is my background code.

```
body {
   background-image: url(images/contact.jpg);
   background-position: center center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-size: 100% auto;
   background-color:#245528;
}

/* For mobile devices */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   body {   
      background-image: url(images/background-photo-mobile-devices.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks like he enabled the "Request desktop site"

Comment: Depends on browser , IOS default browser safari and android Chrome.